# Raising Error: NotRegistered when I use Flask with Celery

Tags: flask, celery

**Description**

Hi, I'm learning Celery, and I read a blog.>>
[Celery and the Flask Application Factory Pattern - miguelgrinberg.com](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern)

So I wrote a small program to run Flask with Celery

**Code**

app.__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__, broker='amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/')

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @celery.task
    def add(x, y):
        print x+y

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        add.delay(1, 3)
        return 'Hello World!'

    return app
```

manage.py

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

celery_worker_1.py

```
from app import celery, create_app()

f_app = create_app()
f_app.app_context().push()
```

celery_worker_2.py

```
from app import celery, create_app

@celery.task
def foo():
    print 'Balabala...'

f_app = create_app()
f_app.app_context().push()
```

**Problem**

When I run the Flask server and celery useing:

```
celery -A celery_worker_1 worker -l
```

the Celery raised NotRegistered Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 363, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 349, in
_fast_trace_task
    return _tasks[task].__trace__(uuid, args, kwargs, request)[0]   File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\app\registry.py", line 26, in __missing__
    raise self.NotRegistered(key) NotRegistered: 'app.add'
```

But instead of using celery_worker_2:

```
celery -A celery_worker_2 worker -l info
```

the task run correctly:

```
[2015-11-28 15:45:56,299: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: app.add[cbe5e1d6-c5df-4141-9db1-e6313517c202]
[2015-11-28 15:45:56,302: WARNING/Worker-1] 4
[2015-11-28 15:45:56,371: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.add[cbe5e1d6-c5df-4141-9db1-e6313517c202] succeeded in 0.0699999332428s: None
```

Why can't the Celery run correctly with the code of celery_worker_1?

> *PS: I'm not good at English, you can point it out to me if you can't understand, I'd like to describe again. ThankS!*

Comment: not sure, but why do you have `create_appp()` in `celery_worker_1.py`'s first line ?

Comment: @ddr2 Sorry, it's a mitake, I have corrected it.